# Is there a way to leave bluetooth on while turning cell service off - a near airplane mode?

Tags: bluetooth, cellular-radio, airplane-mode, google-pixel-4

For my Google Pixel 4 on Android: I often go sailing out in the ocean or motorbiking in distant woods where there is no cell phone signal. I want to leave Bluetooth on so I can listen to podcasts, music and books through my ear buds, but turn cell phone service off so it is not using up power searching for towers that aren't there. Is there a way (or an app) to do this?

Comment: [Mandatory cartoon:](https://heise.cloudimg.io/v7/_www-heise-de_/imgs/18/1/2/6/3/5/5/9/gross-163291294902e030.jpeg?org_if_sml=1&q=85&width=1600) "New device found: Airbus A-310. Start autoconfig? [Yes|No]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Newer phones do not automatically turn off bluetooth when you enable airplane mode. On yours:

- Turn airplane mode on
- Then turn Bluetooth on

Comment: Sad, I had hoped for some developer settings or so to change this behavior

Comment: As far as I remember Google mentioned that the airplane mode is now capable of learning what you want to switch off by enabling airplane mode and what not. In the beginning airplane mode works as it was but if you e.g. multiple times re-enable WiFi and Bluetooth Android will remember this and adapt airplane mode accordingly.